# PHPMailer, AddStringAttachment and Data URI Scheme

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have converted the contents of a `canvas` element to data (URI Scheme) using `toDataURL()` (`$contact_image_data`) and I want to send this via email as an attachment. This is currently how I have PHPMailer set up:

```
$contact_image_data="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo[...]";
$filename="test.png"; 
$encoding = "base64"; 
$type = "image/png";
$mail->AddStringAttachment($contact_image_data, $filename, $encoding, $type);
```

I am wondering if this is actually possible, and if so, what steps I am missing.

I can send an email, attach a file named “test.png” which contains the contents of `$contact_image_data`, but it doesn’t actually create an image.

Any help would be *much* appreciated.

Samuel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should be possible. Are you calling toDataURL() with the 'image/png' MIME type so it knows how to output it?

Try breaking your script into two components - make sure you really have a PNG *then* try mailing it.

For example, will test.png open on your computer when written?..

```
<?php
$contact_image_data="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo[...]";
$fp = fopen('test.png', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $contact_image_data);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: Thank you,

That was really helpful—it was only after playing with `fwrite` that I found this http://canvaspaint.org/blog/2007/01/saving-images/#comments which gave me my answer.

Cheers!

Comment: Archived version of the link referred in above comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20110305022152/http://canvaspaint.org/blog/2007/01/saving-images/

Answer (score 19):

It turns out I needed to strip the `data:image/png;base64,` section and `base64_decode()` the data:

```
$contact_image_data="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA";
$data = substr($contact_image_data, strpos($contact_image_data, ","));
$filename="test.png"; 
$encoding = "base64"; 
$type = "image/png";
$mail->AddStringAttachment(base64_decode($data), $filename, $encoding, $type);
```

Comment: If you don't want to substr the DataURI, you can also get the data with `file_get_contents` like this: `$data = file_get_contents($contact_image_data);`