# PHP Mailer - Attachments not sending properly

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

When I send a message with a string attachment, the string attachment when opened only gives a 1 and in the email sorce it says

```
--b1_5a1a74831dfa0ce86353d222b95078c6
Content-Type: text/html; name="apperley-invoice-20017.html"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="apperley-invoice-20017.html"

MQ==


--b1_5a1a74831dfa0ce86353d222b95078c6--
```

Im using this code to add the attachment:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($invoicehtml,$filename,'base64','text/html');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this here:

[PHPMailer, AddStringAttachment and Data URI Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201955/phpmailer-addstringattachment-and-data-uri-scheme)

Based on the fact that you are getting a base64 result, I'd imagine you either need to change the encoding method to quoted-printable or 8-bit, or decode the $invoicehtml first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the source of your problem but I think think you should **[try SwiftMailer instead](http://swiftmailer.org/)**.

Comment: I have the exact same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that $invoicehtml contains 1. Check your inputs.