# PHP Mailer send an mysql blob object

Tags: php, mysql, blob, phpmailer

I am storing a pdf or text file in mysql blob object, and I am trying to send that as a attachment in the mail using php mailer.

I am sending the mail like .

```
$mail->AddAddress($pr_email);
$mail->Subject = "Meeting Invitation -$meeting_name";

$mail->AddStringAttachment($data);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body =$message;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    $message= "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    header("Location:userprofile.php?Message={$message}");
}
```

Where `$data`  came from

```
$tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$fp     = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$data = addslashes($data);
fclose($fp);
$query = "UPDATE demo_meeting SET attachment='$data' where meetingID='$mtngid'";
$results = mysql_query($query);
```

Now I am receiving the mail as an attachment but content is not there, it is only showing  `0K`.

Please tell me what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new
 code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the
 [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the
 [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared
 statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use
 [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this
 article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose
 PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

As I can see [here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201955/phpmailer-addstringattachment-and-data-uri-scheme), you have ot pass additional parameters to AddStringAttachment: the mime type and the file name.

```
$filename="test.png";
$encoding = "base64"; 
$type = "image/png";
$mail->AddStringAttachment(base64_decode($data), $filename, $encoding, $type);
```

Also, NEVER use `addslashes` to "secure" a mysql field, you have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead (or, use [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) driver which won't be marked obsolete anytime soon)

Comment: He/she should probably also insert the data in the database using `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `addslashes`

Comment: Indeed, I didn't paid attention!!

Comment: type is required what if i am trying to pass a pdf  instead ?  can we type as an optional ?

Comment: If you don't know the file type, you should have a look to file_info function. If you're sure it's PDF, just replace "image/png" by "application/pdf"