# sending php excel as attachment using php mail

Tags: php, phpmailer, phpexcel

I have the following:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_start();
$objWriter->save("php://output");
$xlsData = ob_get_contents();
$xlsData1= "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData);
ob_end_clean();


        //Require for mailing functionality
        require_once('../../PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');

        //Send mail function
        $mail= new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
        $sender ="emailadddress";
        $mail->SetFrom($sender);
        $mail->AddAddress('emailaddress');   
        $mail->Subject="Combined repair and production report from ".$reportDate;
        $encoding = "base64"; 
        //$type = "image/png";
        $mail->AddStringAttachment(base64_decode($xlsData1), "combined_report".$reportDate."xlsx");  
        //$mail->AddAttachment($xlsData, $filename);
        $message= "Please see attached combined report";
        $message = "</body></html>";              
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);    

        if(!$mail->Send()) 
        {
            $response =  array(
                'op' => 'failed',
                'file' => "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData)
            );
        } 
        else 
        {
            $response =  array(
                'op' => 'ok',
                'file' => "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData)
            );

        } 





die(json_encode($response));
pg_close($conn);
```

this sends an email with an attachemnt but the attachment is a blank file. When I try to save it it has the filename and the extension like this: "filenamexlsx" so it looks like it is not getting the correct xlsx format. I have tried this too:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment("data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData);
```

I have also tried:

```
    $encoding = "base64"; 
    $type = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; // and :application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    $mail->AddStringAttachment(base64_decode($xlsData1), "combined_report".$reportDate."xlsx",$encoding,$type);
```

I also tried using the `AddAttachment()` instead of the string attachment and there is no attachment on the email when I do that.

I have followed :
 [php send e-mail with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092821/php-send-e-mail-with-attachment?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and have also looked at multiple things out there like [PHPMailer, AddStringAttachment and Data URI Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201955/phpmailer-addstringattachment-and-data-uri-scheme/1202577#1202577)

but it doesnt appear to be working :( any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `$reportDate."xlsx"` should be `$reportDate.".xlsx"`

Comment: well yours was not letting me accept as an answer and I didn't want others stopping for such a small mistake. sorry I am kinda new with posting quesitons etc.

Comment: Would you happen to know why I still get an error saying that the file is corrupt? can you help me spot any other errors?

Comment: I figured it out thanks... Just in case it helps anybody else in the future you have to **'$xlsData = ob_get_contents();
$contact_image_data="data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData);
$data = substr($contact_image_data, strpos($contact_image_data, ","));** and then **$mail->AddStringAttachment(base64_decode($data),"combined_report_.xlsx",$encoding,$type);**

Answer (score 0):

I think there is mistake in your file name. Your file name should be **filename.xlsx** not this **filenamexlsx**

Comment: jeez, you're right the stupid php syntax was throwing me off... thanks appreciate the help!